# How to suppress warnings from framework

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to reduce the number of warnings in my project. And I found that some warnings come from some libraries (*.framework)

I searched around, but nothing help.

So my question is: How can I suppress those warnings from frameworks?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove deprecation warnings without removing the deprecated API from your code. It's a way in which Xcode tells you that you should avoid using or at least be aware of the consequences of using the APIs which can be removed in future versions.

I don't think that the native frameworks would give any other warnings. So replacing the deprecated API by the recommended one is the proper way to suppress these warnings.